# Disable click animation in recyclerView

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView I just want to disable the animation when an item is clicked

Any help is welcome

thanks in advance

Comment: and how to you starting the animation? post that code

Answer (score 2):

You can disable it through `recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);`

Comment: Currently, this causes this exception to be thrown:
NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.SimpleItemAnimator.setSupportsChangeAnimations(boolean)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

in your viewHolder class

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View rootView;

public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    rootView = itemView;

    }
}
   @Override
```

and then in onBindViewHolder

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.rootView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               //overridden default onClick
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the `clickable` property to `true` on your item's layout's root node.

Example `item_layout.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
    android:clickable="true"
    ...
    >

    ...

</LinearLayout
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are talking about touch `ripple` effect.

To disable this effect, just set a background `color` to the root layout of your `RecyclerView's` item layout's `XML`.

**For example:**

```
// recyclerview_item.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_aaa"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff0000">

    ................
    .......................

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this will help~